# How can I pass form data from one html file to another without JS/PHP?

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I'm learning basic web dev and started with HTML, CSS, Bootstrap. Haven't touched PHP or anything server side yet.

What I've done so far is I've created a pretty basic registration form with 5 fields and what I'm trying to do is display the input of those fields in a table that I've created on another page. The submit button has the "method" and  action. Now, I've Googled a ton to find some solutions and have gone through most of the questions of this site but I still can't find out to achieve what I'm trying to do without the use of PHP/JS.

So, is it even possible to read form data from another page like this without the use of JS/PHP? If so, how do I proceed and what needs to be done? I can post the source code but I don't think it's going to help since there isn't much there, everything else is working fine except for finding a solution to this.

Thank you.

Comment: You simply can't, you need to learn deeper into web development

Comment: @AlonEitan can you kindly guide me further then? What I've seen so far is it can be done with JS, so should I learn JS now? Anything (script, codes etc) specifically to help with this particular query?

Comment: If you want to go with interface stuff like DOM (HTML) manipulation then learn JS first. If you want to handle the backend then learn PHP first - Note that you will also need to learn SQL in order to store the data from the HTML <form> on the server

Comment: I'll start with JS first since I'm planning to touch backend a bit later so it's better to perfect one thing first and then slowly move on to the next. Thank you!

Comment: @AlonEitan one last query, sorry. For using JS to transfer data between pages, I'll have to use GET method, right? POST method only works when using PHP or/and a server is connected, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is long gone but I *was* actually able to resolve my problem without using anything other than basic HTML , so here's how I did it for anyone else who's trying to find the answer to problem (probably not, you don't usually do this professionally and basically this was a challenge from a friend).

So, two things.

1. SessionStorage
2. LocalStorage

This is built-in to your browser and you can use it to achieve simple tasks by simply assigning values to it. They'll remain there and you can use however you want.

But, as the name implies, sessionstorage will only retain those values during the session (the time you have your browser open for) while localstorage can retain it indefinitely. Not sure if I can link other sites over here so just Google these terms to learn more and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You need *a* programming language.

If you want to do it entirely client-side, then that has to be JS.

If you want to do it server-side (which allows you to access the data and, optionally, make it available to other people, instead of limiting it to the user of the browser) then you can use any programming language at all (although JS and PHP are among the most common choices).

Since you are trying to create a registration page, you'll need to use server-side programming.

Comment: well, with this registration form, I'm just it locally for self-learning so it's not like anyone else is going to be using it. Can you guide me specifically with regards to JS on how to solve this particular problem that I have? Or should I just go through some courses on JS, it will obviously be helpful in the future since I'll have to learn it someday but with this problem, how should i proceed using JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You necessarily need to use JavaScript / PHP.

Since you are just starting, I would highly recommend you to check out the [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp) tutorials on HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, Bootstrap and jQuery.

:)

Comment: Thank you, will do. Learnt HTML and CSS from there, will check out the rest too.